# setting automatic pk to autoincrement in workbench

Tags: workbench

I am working in workbench and when i create a table workbench creates PK atribute for me.
Is there any way i could make this attribute be set to autoincrement value as well?

Comment: I think if its not part of workbench functionality (which i dont know why it wouldnt be) I think it still should be possible to make it happen by messing with actual memory possibly by using an external program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Under database, select `Alter Table` on table in question. Check `AI` checkmark next to column that you are using as `primary key` (PK and NN should be checked as well).

[image: Auto Increment checkmark]